# Proper usage of Auxilliary Verbs

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs, past-participles

Why is this sentence correct?

"Nine dogs are caught and one cat has escaped"

I immediately notice that the auxiliary verb "are" was before caught which is in its past-participle form so I assume that it should be were instead of are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "are" isn't an auxiliary there, but the main verb for the first clause. The word "caught" is functioning as an adjective in that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing tenses; incorrectly in my opinion.  Here are my attempts at correcting what I perceive to be a grammatically incorrect phrase.

"Nine dogs were caught and one cat escaped"
"Nine dogs are caught and one cat escapes"
"Nine dogs have been caught and one cat has escaped"